# jQuery get page which hast parent in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The following code works perfectly fine for "normal" wordpress pages without a parent page, BUT if the requested page has a parent I get nothing and I can't get the code to work (alert box never came) after 5h of web-searching and trial and error.

JS/jQuery here:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//get the page via page slug
  jQuery.get("thePageSlug").success(function(data){
    //get the content div of the found page
    jQuery(data).find("#content").appendTo("#content");
    alert("finally.....");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is on topic here, and I'm not suggesting we migrate the question, but you *may* find more focused help over at [wordpress.se] (though I'd imagine most Wordpress devs are likely to be quite active here on Stack Overflow as well).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you used relative path in .get function. Try to use absolute path so that it will not get conflict with Wrodpress Permalink.

Try this instead:

```
jQuery.get("/thePageSlug")...........
```

Or even:

```
jQuery.get("http://your.domain/path/to/your/thePageSlug")...........
```

Code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //get the page via page slug
        jQuery.get("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/thePageSlug").success(function(data){
            //get the content div of the found page
            jQuery(data).find("#content").appendTo("#content");
            alert("finally.....");
        });
    });
</script>
```